# Convert text with tabs to a valide JSON with regex

Tags: javascript, json, regex, regex-group, audacity

I try to convert this plain txt exported from a audio sofware (audacity)

```
0.147652    0.983684    noing_grf
2.316547    3.609503    boing_4r4
```

To a valid **json** objet format like this
[image]

```
{
    'noing_grf': { start: 0.147652, end: 0.983684 },
    'boing_4r4': { start: 2.316547, end: 3.609503 },
}
```

The pattern i try is this one `([^\t\n]+)`
But i think i need a full example to perform.

Any Regex pro can help me to do this, am not succeed at all ! 
My target it to export label and regions from the audio data track, than load in js and convert in a json format to manage **spriteAudio** like this API.
http://pixijs.io/pixi-sound/examples/sprites.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to use a regex to perform this? 
You could do this very simple in javascript (or in any other programming language).

```
const data = `0.147652  0.983684    noing_grf
2.316547    3.609503    boing_4r4`;

const dictionary = {};
const lines = data.split("\n");
lines.forEach(line => {
    line = line.split("\t");
    dictionary[line[2]] = { start: line[0], end: line[1] };
});
```

the resulting dictionary would have the format you wanted:

```
{
    noing_grf: { start: '0.147652', end: '0.983684' },
    boing_4r4: { start: '2.316547', end: '3.609503' }
}
```

Comment: Ho waiitt !!! I absolutely do not think about this simple method, why I complicate my life!
Thank you , your are genius. :)